# F# create new list populated from other list

Tags: list, dictionary, object, f#, match

In my backend code, I am fetching data from database and my query returns a list of Product-objects. However, since I don't need to return all of the product objects' data to the front-end, I would like to handpick the returned properties (i.e. not all properties of the Product-objects).

I am trying to use List.map to handpick only some of the properties.

```
let products = session.Query<Product<IProductVariant>>("where id < 1000")
let returnValue = List.collect(fun product -> (product.ID, product.Name)) products
```

But the above doesn't work because "product" is an object, not an instance of Product class.  I've tried formatting it again like this, but to no avail.

```
let returnValue = List.map(fun obj -> (
   match (obj) with
   | ProductClass product -> (product.ID, product.Name)
   | None -> ignore
)) products
```

I'm only learning F# after since inheriting the maintenance of an F# project at work. So, my attempted solution may be in totally wrong direction. Please advise on how to proceed, if my solution attempt is totally wrong.

Comment: In the first snippet you use `List.collect` and not `List.map` as you stated. Try to use `List.map`. The result will be a list of tuples of (ID, Name), likely `int * string`. Tip: Don't use paretheses where they're not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I cannot reproduce the problem, a simplified version without the parts you did not specify might be:

```
type Product = { Id: int; Name: string; Price: decimal }
let products = [ { Id = 42; Name = "Waterfall"; Price = 3.14m } ]
let retVal = List.map (fun p -> (p.Id, p.Name)) products
```

Here, F# inferred that `retVal` is of type `list<int * string>`.

Let's pretend that, for whatever reason, the type is somewhat wrong. We can provoke this:

```
open System
type Product = { Id: int; Name: string; Price: decimal }
let products = [ { Id = 42; Name = "Waterfall"; Price = 3.14m } ]
type WrongProduct = { Id: Guid; Name: string option }
let retVal = List.map (fun p -> (p.Id, p.Name)) products
```

The simple addition of `WrongProduct` leads to

> error FS0001: Type mismatch.

There are (at least) two things we can do about this:

Specify the type of the parameter in your mapping function:

```
let retVal = List.map (fun (p: Product) -> (p.Id, p.Name)) products
```

or pipe the products into the mapping function, such that the compiler 'knows' the type of the elements when looking at the function:

```
let retVal = products |> List.map (fun p: Product -> (p.Id, p.Name))
```

The latter is the idiomatic way in F#

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it helped me to go into right direction. Now I have corrected my syntax problems and I am battling with the error message "`This expression was expected to have type 'IProduct list' but here has type 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<IProduct>'`". My code is as follows: 

`let queryResult = session.Query<IProduct>("where data is not null")
\n
List.map(fun (p) -> (p.ProductId, p.AssortmentGrade)) queryResult`

And the 'queryResult' variable (when I hover over it in Visual Studio) is displayed of being type "IProduct list"?

Comment: Instead of `List.map` you could try `Seq.map` or create a list of products: `let prodList = List.ofSeq products` and then map over that list.

Comment: @silvercoins did you succeed?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! I succeeded :)